# bash - make command not found

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have created make file named `Makefile` in my linux ec2 server.

```
all: a b

a: daemon.cpp dictionary_exclude.cpp
        g++ -o a daemon.cpp dictionary_exclude.cpp -lpthread -std=c++0x -L.

b: user_main.cpp client.cpp
        g++ -o b user_main.cpp client.cpp
```

I could run each of this independently successfull.

But when I execute

```
make
make -f Makefile
```

It says make : `-bash: make: command not found`

Any idea? I can see manually for make is available through man make

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544200/how-can-i-use-install-make-on-the-amazon-linux-ami-for-ec2

Comment: `man make` will give you some documentation about the `make` command. you can install the documentation without installing `make` itself, so `man make` is *not* a good test to check whether a program is installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please execute following command to install make in your system

```
sudo yum install build-essential
```

Comment: `build-essential` is for `apt-get`, the `"Development Tools"` package is the equivalent under `yum`

Answer (score 7):

In CentOS or Red Hat, try this:

```sh
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you have not installed binutils http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils or you have not set your PATH variable to the correct location of bin utils.

Comment: `make` is not part of the `binutils` package.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install build-essential` on Ubuntu 16 worked for me