# Is there a way to install and use gcc on MacBook M1?

Tags: gcc, terminal, clang, openmp, apple-m1

I am trying to install and work with gcc compiler on my MacBook M1. I have installed gcc using home-brew, but I did not find a way to use it on the terminal in my Mac. I wanted to download a tool that uses gcc compiler for its installation. Specifically, it looks like the tool needs OpenMP and clang does not support it.

Error message when I run make command:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

When I change the path to the gcc installation path, I am unable to run basic commands like ls in the terminal. I understand that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700755/bash-make-command-not-found) is the reason for that. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

My (now rather old) discussion of this is on my CpuFun blog: [Setting up the Apple M1 for Native Code Development from the Command Line](https://cpufun.substack.com/p/setting-up-the-apple-m1-for-native)

The short version is

1. Be very careful about running X86_64 compiled shells. (You don't want to!)
2. Use `brew` to install the relevant native compilers, but make sure that you have added the correct (`/opt/homebrew/...`) path to your `PATH` envirable. (See the [Homebrew 3.0.0 release notes](https://brew.sh/2021/02/05/homebrew-3.0.0/).)

Without more information about how you changed your `PATH` it's impossible to say what is wrong in your case, but it does sound as if you simply assigned a single directory to the `PATH`, rather than adding to it...

Remember that there are a  number of useful commands to help you diagnose problems like this:-

- `which` *command*
  to tell you where *command* is coming from.
- The `--version` flag to the compilers to show which compiler they are.
- `brew` may not make a link for the name `gcc` alone, but rather install `gcc-11` (or whatever), so you you may need to do that explicitly.